# Workers not able to start in Distributed R

Tags: distributed-r

When I run this command:

```
distributedR_start (inst = 0, mem=0, cluster_conf="cluster_conf.xml", log=2)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : No workers are registered
```

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <MasterConfig>
        <ServerInfo>
            <Hostname>10.234.31.166</Hostname>
            <StartPortRange>50000</StartPortRange>
            <EndPortRange>50100</EndPortRange>
        </ServerInfo>
        <Workers>
        <Worker>
            <Hostname>10.234.31.165</Hostname>
            <StartPortRange>50000</StartPortRange>
            <EndPortRange>50100</EndPortRange>
            <Executors>0</Executors>
            <SharedMemory>0</SharedMemory>
        </Worker>
        <Worker>
            <Hostname>10.234.31.167</Hostname>
            <StartPortRange>50000</StartPortRange>
            <EndPortRange>50100</EndPortRange>
            <Executors>0</Executors>
            <SharedMemory>0</SharedMemory>
        </Worker>
    </Workers>
</MasterConfig>
```

My master Log file is `R_master_hduser_10.234.31.166.50000.log`

Log file message:

```
2015-Apr-14 08:40:33.263117 [INFO] Master node is listening at 50000 port.
2015-Apr-14 08:40:33.263410 [INFO] Resource Manager Created
2015-Apr-14 08:40:33.263451 [INFO] Master Initialization done
2015-Apr-14 08:40:34.290737 [INFO] Master awaiting HELLO handshaking with Workers.
2015-Apr-14 08:41:34.290973 [ERROR] No workers are registered
2015-Apr-14 08:41:35.296232 [INFO] PrestoMasterHanlder Shutdown is called
2015-Apr-14 08:41:35.297740 [INFO] distributedR shutdown complete.
```

Already i have tried all the steps mention in this forum like master can able to login without password to worker.  I have also cross checked the `.bashrc` entry for the `DISTRIBUTED_HOME` path in all the systems, and it has not created any worker log file.  It seems that the worker not able to give a handshake to master.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you confirm you can ssh from 10.234.31.166 to 10.234.31.165 and 10.234.31.167 without password input?